# Is it good practice to make a constant that varies based on the user language?

Tags: php, constants

I'm making constants in my PHP application to organize its responses, and I'm planning to add foreign language support soon.  Here's what I'm doing right now: `define('SOME_SYSTEM_MESSAGE',array('EN' => 'This is the system message!') [USER_LANGUAGE]);` (I know that the [ ] syntax is only supported in PHP 5.5, I have a backwards-compatible function for older versions).  Is that good practice for coding, or should I keep the messages in an array (like $en for english messages or $fr for french messages), or some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on where you want to go with your application.
Your proposed solution might work if you want to keep it mostly limited to yourself / your team.

But if other people should use your code later on or if you want to be able to translate it into other languages, it would be handy to have files like .po or .csv which translaters can handle.

Comment: At the moment, it's just me working on it.  I didn't know that PO files were an official part of PHP.  I'm marking your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Constants can not hold arrays, constants are limited to the following types: null, boolean, integer, string or resource.

If you want to localize your application into different languages use gettext or other localization technologies. You should prefer components instead of reinventing something.

As an Example: The Symfony Framework contains an (standalone) [Translation-Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/introduction.html).

Comment: Constants can hold serialized arrays - which can be unserialized on usage ;)

Comment: Serialized arrays are strings. You can not overwrite constants.

Comment: I didn't mention anything about overwriting constants. Your first sentence doesn't make sense - sure, arrays can change, but so can strings. In PHP, we don't have immutable scalar types.

Comment: okay, i changed it to a documentation alike explaination. Thanks Jimbo.

Comment: @tr0y It's not holding an array, it's holding the item USER_LANGUAGE from the array.

Comment: yes, i see ( ugly syntax ). Whatever, constants are not best practice to implement localization.